# Compilation errors with inline assembly code in c file, probably with branching

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I have below code. When i try to compile its giving errors mentioned after the code snippet.

```
void func()
  __asm__ (
    "mfspr     12, 1017;"
    "rotrwi    12,12,%0;"
    "andi.     11, 12, %1;"
    "beq       done;"
"3:;"
    "mfspr     12, 1017;"
    "andi.     11, 12, %2;"
    "bne       3b;"
    "ori       12, 12, %2;"
    "mtspr     1017, 12;"
    "isync;"
"3:;"
    "mfspr     12, 1017;"
    "andi.     11, 12, %2;"
    "bne       3b;"
"done:;"
    ::"r"(31), "r"(1), "r"(2048));     
}
```

Errors:

```
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:3607: Error: bad expression
{standard input}:3607: Error: missing ')'
{standard input}:3607: Error: missing ')'
{standard input}:3607: Error: syntax error; found `r', expected `,'
{standard input}:3607: Error: junk at end of line: `r9)!31)&((%r9)|31),0,31'
```

I think some problem with branching i am doing, but i am not exactly sure whats wrong. Can anyone help me fixing this?

Comment: Which architecture are you compiling for? Please can you try using the --save-temps option with the compiler to get the assembly code produced by the compiler, and then post the relevant section here. You should see something strange on line 3607...

Comment: I am compiling for e500mc. From the --save-temps i got this at 3607.....mfspr     12, 1017;rotrwi    12,12,%r9;andi.     11, 12, %r10;beq       done;3b:;mfspr     12, 1017;andi.     11, 12, %r8;bne       3b;ori       12, 12, %r8;mtspr     1017, 12;isync;3b:;mfspr     12, 1017;andi.     11, 12, %r8;bne       3b;done:;.

Comment: Maybe the assembler does not like everything being on a single line. Try replacing each ";" with "\n".

Comment: I replaced ";" with "\n" but still the same error. Here the snippet at line. rotrwi    12, 12, %r9

Comment: `rotrwi` takes operands `register, register, immediate`. You tried `immediate, immediate, register` and that's invalid.

Comment: actually 12 means r12 register. Since my compiler isn't recognizing r12, i directly used 12.

Comment: @Jester has the right idea - you are using `register, register, register` but should be using `register, register, immediate`. Is there a `rotrw` instruction? can you use it instead?

Comment: Since you pass in an immediate anyway, just change the `r` constraint to `i` maybe?

Comment: @Jack is 12 wouldn't be taken as r12 by compiler? BTE there is no instruction called rotw, it seems.

Comment: @Jester you mean to input 31 which is a constant not variable, i should use "i" instead "r"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
  void func()
    __asm__ (
      "mfspr     12, 1017\n"
      "rotrwi    12,12,%0\n"
      "andi.     11, 12, %1\n"
      "beq       done\n"
  "3:\n"
      "mfspr     12, 1017\n"
      "andi.     11, 12, %2\n"
      "bne       3b\n"
      "ori       12, 12, %2\n"
      "mtspr     1017, 12\n"
      "isync\n"
  "3:\n"
      "mfspr     12, 1017\n"
      "andi.     11, 12, %2\n"
      "bne       3b\n"
  "done:\n"
      ::"i"(31), "i"(1), "i"(2048));
  }
```

`;` changed to `\n` to make it easier to see which line(s) are wrong.

`"r"(N)` changed to `"i"(N)` for instructions that use immediates instead of registers.